# Handling exceptions when running nunit tests from console application

Tags: c#, exception, nunit

I'm trying to run nunit test cases from the console application using reflection. I get an exception which is not handled by my catch block. Could you give an advice how to handle all the exceptions from the invoked test methods?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Take all classes of the current assebly to which TestFixture attribute is applied
    var testClasses = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(c =>
    {
        var attributes = c.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestFixtureAttribute));
        return attributes.Any();
    });
    foreach (var testClass in testClasses)
    {
        var testMethods = testClass.GetMethods().Where(m =>
        {
            var attributes = m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (TestAttribute));
            return attributes.Any();
        });
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(testClass);
        foreach (var method in testMethods)
        {
            try
            {
                Action action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Action), 
                                                                 instance, method);
                action();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The aggregation exception occurs in try block and isn't caught.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception, and which type is it, and what is the message of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear why you're trying to do this, since there's already nunit-console that can run unit tests from a console application.  It's also unclear what exception you don't think is being caught, but I suspect it's not the type you think it is.  I took your code and put it into a fresh console application, along with some very basic tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeFailingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Fails()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, 0);
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void TestExceptionExpected()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestThrows()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void TestThrowsExpected()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

All of the tests that threw exceptions were caught by the line:

```
catch (Exception e)
```

This makes sense, since none of them threw an `AggregateException`.  I suspect whichever test you are running is also not throwing one and is also being caught by your outer catch.  A good start might be to rewrite this block as:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", e.GetType().Name, e.Message));
}
```

So that you can see any exception types that you aren't handling.  At a very basic level, you may have to account for `AssertionException` for example.

If you want to support a similar feature set to other nunit runners you're also going to need to pay attention to the `ExpectedException` attribute on any methods you run and check to see if that exception is thrown when you invoke the method.  You'll also need to check for the `Ignored` attribute...

As has been mentioned in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30324973/592182), you may also need to pay attention to other test attributes such as `TestCase` and `TestCaseSource` if you want to capture *all* of the tests in the assembly.

Unless you're writing this as a learning exercise, you might want to reconsider your approach.